# Разделить строку на массив слов c++

Tags: c++, строки

В Java есть функция `.split` которая разделяет строку вокруг регулярного выражения и  возвращает массив строк, так вот есть ли в C++ (стандартной библиотеке) аналогичная функция?

Comment: Ну, предположим, `scanf`, точнее, `sscanf`. И аналог из плюсов - istringstream.

Comment: каждая задача по своему разделяет строку на слова. Что такое слово, это еще нужно определить( the best 'это одно слово или два? Mr. NIkolai как разделить на слова, точку убрать или нет? Все это вопросы, которые нужно оставлять на решения пользователей, поэтому в C++ нет  такой функции, поскольку она  не будет широко применима

Comment: В яве применима, а в крестах нет?! Ну вы тоже палку-то не перегинайте, а то треснит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class itIn, class itOut, class T, class F>
itIn split(itIn it, itIn end, itOut out, T sep, F func) {
    while(it != end) {
        auto slice_end (std::find(it, end, sep));
        *out++ = func(it, slice_end);
        if(slice_end == end) { return end; }
        it = std::next(slice_end);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string str = "приём*приём*foo*bar*baz";
    std::list<std::string> l;
    split(std::begin(str), std::end(str), std::back_inserter(l), '*', [](auto itA, auto itB) {
        return std::string(itA, itB);
    });

    copy(std::begin(l), std::end(l), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>{std::cout, " "});
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

ну или `boost::split`